# Does Monkey Runner need any Scripting language to Run

Tags: user-interface, crash, monkeyrunner

Does Monkey Runner needs any Scripting language to Run , actually my question  is Monkey runner Only Click the UI of the App, Here i need to Check where my app getting crash?

Answer (score 0):

You should start from `adb logcat` instead of monkeyrunner if you are trying to find out the reason your app is crashing.